# Get last updated time for all items grouped by category

Tags: mysql

here is my table of items:

```
id (int)
category_id (int)
title (varchar 255)
updated_timestamp (int)
```

Each item has a category_id. Let's say I have this data:

```
1  |  14  |  item 1  |  1376164492
2  |  11  |  item 2  |  1376164508
3  |  12  |  item 3  |  1376164512
4  |  14  |  item 4  |  1376164532
5  |  12  |  item 5  |  1376164542
6  |  11  |  item 6  |  1376164552
```

My goal is to get last update timestamp for each category.
As a result I need this:

```
11 = 1376164522 (greatest value for all items with category_id = 11)
12 = 1376164542 (greatest value for all items with category_id = 12)
14 = 1376164532 (greatest value for all items with category_id = 14)
```

Here is my SQL:

```
SELECT 
    `category_id`, `updated_timestamp` 
FROM 
    `my_table` 
GROUP BY 
    `category_id` 
ORDER BY 
    `updated_timestamp` 
DESC
```

But when I run it I have a result like this:

```
11 = 1376164508 (lowest value for all items with category_id = 11)
12 = 1376164512 (greatest value for all items with category_id = 12)
14 = 1376164492 (greatest value for all items with category_id = 14)
```

Another words, DESC does not work. What I am doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: use `MAX()`, try this query:
`SELECT 
    `category_id`, MAX(`updated_timestamp` )
FROM 
    `Table1` 
GROUP BY 
    `category_id` 
ORDER BY 
    `updated_timestamp` 
DESC`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM `my_table` a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM `my_table` b
    WHERE b.`category_id` = a.`category_id`
    AND b.`updated_timestamp` > a.`updated_timestamp`
)
ORDER BY `updated_timestamp`
```

Comment: @PaulDenisevich I've updated my answer to return all of the appropriate row data (and to make it different to Conrad's answer)

Answer (score 2):

This query allows you to get all columns in the table.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    items a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  category_id, MAX(updated_timestamp) updated_timestamp
            FROM    items
            GROUP   BY category_id
        ) b ON a.category_id = b.category_id AND
                a.updated_timestamp = b.updated_timestamp
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2109/1)

Comment: +1 This one's great as it gets the appropriate `id` and `title` as well

Answer (score 2):

Try the query as follow by adding `MAX(`updated_timestamp`)`

```
SELECT 
    `category_id`, MAX(`updated_timestamp` )
FROM 
    `Table1` 
GROUP BY 
    `category_id` 
ORDER BY 
    `updated_timestamp` 
DESC
```

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/214d0/1)